# How to display exact months for a given year in decimal

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var schemeduration = '1.5';// 1 year and 5 months
var schemeduration= (parseFloat(schemeduration) * 12).toFixed(0) ;
alert(schemeduration);

1.1 = 13 months
1.2 = 14 months
1.3 = 15 months
1.4 = 16 months
1.5 = 17 months
1.6 = 18 months
1.7 = 19 months
1.8 = 20 months
1.9 = 21 months
1.10 = 22 months
1.11 = 23 months
1.12 = 24 months
```

how to display exact months for the given years in decimal.For the above given it should display 17 but i am getting the value as 18.  There are 12 months in a year i need the output calculated in terms of months

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NsBxX/)

Comment: What is your question? 1.5 * 12 is 18...

Comment: `12 * 1.5` will give `18` no matter what. How is the expected value 17?

Comment: i meant see there are 12 months in a year i need the output calculated in terms of months

Comment: Ahh, so by 1.5, you mean *1 year and 5 months*, and not *1.5 years*. Is it?

Comment: @Rup just fetching the value from a text field and storing to variable... u can use the exact data type what is suitable for the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
var schemeduration = '1.5';

if(schemeduration.indexOf('.') === -1) schemeduration += '.0';

var years = Math.floor(parseFloat(schemeduration));
var months = parseInt(schemeduration.split('.')[1], 10);

schemeduration = years * 12 + months;

alert(schemeduration);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NsBxX/1/

Comment: You've got an extra `var` in there ;)

Comment: @techfoobar if there is no months then it will display `Nan` so we need to assign 0 by default to months ..

Answer (score 1):

Do this: [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NsBxX/2/)

```
var schemeduration = '1.5';
var arr = schemeduration.split('.');
var ans = (Number(arr[0]) * 12) + Number(arr[1]);

alert(ans);
```

First you separate the string to two parts which the decimal point as delimiter. Then multiply the year part by 12 (months) and add the months part.

Answer (score 0):

Don't treat the text string '1.10' as a single floating point number. If you do, you cannot see a difference with '1.1'. If you want to nevertheless, your first 1-year 1-month should be '1.01' instead.

To parse your current system, split the input string in two on the period. Then add the first number times 12 to the second number.

Answer (score 0):

You should split on the '.' token, the first value will be *12 since it is in years. Add this to the second value and you are good

```
var schemeduration = '1.5';
var tokens = schemeduration.split('.');
var years = parseInt(tokens[0]);
var months = parseInt(tokens[1]);

alert(years*12+months);
```